# Advantage of fish-eyes lens and Camera Calibration

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, camera-calibration

The purpose of calibration is to calibrated distortion the image.

What's main source of this distortion in the image when the lens is used, for example fish-eyes lens?

Q1-You think we are going to identify some of the objects and using fish-eyes lenses in order to cover a wide view of the environment, Do we need to calibrate the camera? That is, we must correct the image distortions and then identify the objects? Does the corrected image still cover the same amount of objects? If it's not cover all objects of distorted image, then what is the point of taking a wide-angle lens? Wouldn't it be better to use the same flat lens without having to calibrate the camera?

Q2-For calculating the distortion param like intrinsic and extrinsic param and etc, Is need to calculate parameters for all of camera with same specifics independently? That's, the finding parameters of distortion for one camera can be correctly work with other camera with same specifics?

Comment: This question is in dire need of some focusing, because right now it sounds more like you want to start a discussion about how camera lenses or sources that contain any form of distortion will impact object detection. I would say this is a very broad subject, but I also would say that when my first gut reaction is to ask "What exactly do you mean here", then the question is not focused enough. Additionally, you have 2 questions here, something which doesn't fit well with the way Stack Overflow works. Please narrow your question down.

Answer (score 1):

Q1 Answer : You need to dewarp the image/video that comes out of the camera. There are some libraries that do it for you. You can also calibrate the dewarping according to your needs.

When dewarping the fisheye input, the corners of the video feed are a little lost. This won't be a huge loss.

Q2 Answer : Usually you don't have to do a different dewarping configuration based on your camera. But if you want to finetune it, there are parameters for it.

FFmpeg has  [lens correction filter](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#lenscorrection), the parameters to finetune are also present in the link.